# create a count then sum column based on 2 other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table called call_logs sqlfidle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fce856

```
    Date           call_time(slot)  call_duration
    2011-10-01         60                 30
    2011-10-01         60                 15
    2015-10-01        180                 30
    2005-10-05         30                 45
    2020-02-03         90                 30
    2020-05-03         15                 15
    2020-07-03         30                 15
    2005-02-26         30                 15
    2011-10-01         60                 30
    2010-10-01         60                 30
    2007-02-03         90                 30
    2018-05-31         90                 30
    2002-09-31         90                 30
    2009-11-31         90                 30
```

I want a new table with column called `count_duration` that show how many `call_duration` of x had a `call_time` of 60, 90,15,120 took place.

Given a call_time slot of 60 minutes with a call duration of 30, there were only 3 calls with that duration

The output table will look like this:

```
Date           call_time(slot)  call_duration      Count duration
2011-10-01         60                 30              3
2007-02-03         90                 30              2
2005-02-26         30                 15              2
2015-10-01        180                 30              1
2005-10-05         30                 45              1
2020-02-03         90                 30              5
2020-05-03         15                 15              1
```

I try using this query, but I'm afraid I'll have to enter every single permutation, which I' m not sure it's now the best option

```
select MAX(date),
SUM( case when call_time = '60' and call_duration = '15' then 1 else 0) as 60_15
,SUM( case when call_time = '60' and call_duration = '30' then 1 else 0) as 60_30
FROM Table1
group by date
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you're going to post the same question to [multiple forums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/120899/create-a-new-columns-that-shows-the-count-based-on.html), the LEAST you can do is link them to avoid duplication of effort and consistency in information

Comment: How can a "count" generate a value of 34589 for the first row? What formula and what set of values computes that value?  For 2015-10-01 you have a single row - yet your count in sample output is 10? Note - your fiddle sample data is completely different from what you show here.

Comment: @SMor, yes it is different but same concept. the database as multiple years and has rouhgly 2million rows. I'm trying to do is count for every call_time(slot) how for instance of 60 minutes, how many had a call duration of 30 or for every 60 call/slot how many had a call duration of 15

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `group by`?

```
select date, call_time, call_duration, count(*)
from table1
group by date, call_time, call_duration
order by date, count(*) desc;
```

This puts the counts in separate rows rather than separate columns -- that is actually what your results look like.

Comment: the query you provided is just giving me individual count. I do want to know of people who had a call_time of 60 how many had a call duration of 30 or 15. the query you provided is only marking it as 1.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could be looking to GROUP BY date and call_time and crosstab or pivot columns by call_duration.  The call durations are integers?  Something like this

```
select [date], call_time,
       sum(case when call_duration = 15 then 1 else 0) as duration_15
      ,sum(case when call_duration = 30 then 1 else 0) as duration_30
      ,sum(case when call_duration = 45 then 1 else 0) as duration_45
      ,sum(case when call_duration = 60 then 1 else 0) as duration_60
      ,sum(case when call_duration = 90 then 1 else 0) as duration_90
      ,sum(case when call_duration = 180 then 1 else 0) as duration_180
      ,sum(case when call_duration > 180 then 1 else 0) as duration_plus
from Table1
group by [date], call_time
```